# Knockout JS - MVVM pattern, where does my ui logic go?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

This sounds like a stupid question, but thought I would post anyway...

I am just making a simple web app with javascript and html and decided upon Knockout JS for the main framework to manage the UIs. However I am a bit puzzled how to proceed.

My first page is a very simple login page, it just has a username and password box, the problem comes when I want to do thing with the UI. An example would be adding a watermark to the ui boxes, or adding logic around listening to custom events, I could just write it as in-line javascript but I cannot really unit test any of it then.

Originally I was planning to use an MVC style pattern so I could unit test the controller with a mocked view, and just put any ui logic in there.

So is there any acceptable way of doing this without putting it all as in-page logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way mvvm works is that the view should pretty much be a visual representation of that view model, so put your logic in there. If you design it right so your functionality is contained in seperate classes then you can mock them all out easy enough. If you are used to MVC then just see the viewmodel as your controller.

I can see where you are going with your question though, as with complex views you could end up with quite a lot happening within your ViewModel class, but if you just stick to simple oo and encapsulation principles you wont go too far wrong...

So anyway to summarise, put it in your logic in the view model.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can use. There is an [xUnit package for JavaScript called JsUnit](https://github.com/pivotal/jsunit) So it is possible to unit test your JavaScript-based UI logic. The other route as you mentioned is to use the controller to contain the logic and the JavaScript as a "pure" view model. I personally feel that either approach is viable. You just want to make sure that your JavaScript-based view model doesn't become too intimate with the view. :)

Comment: I am using JsTestDriver to test my stuff at the moment, but it all needs to be encapsulated in classes to make the testing worthwhile, and from the initial look at how other people have done this sort of stuff, its just random code sprinkled throughout the model... I prefer the latter method you mention, but I would have expected more people to have these problems when making their sites, couldnt find much on the interwebs about it...